# Netlogo : Uploading a gis shapefile and preventing two polygons from overlapping

Tags: gis, netlogo, patch

Good morning.

I upload a shapefile and ask patches with the centroid of each polygons to set some properties from the shapefile attributes.

```
gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of shpefile)
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  gis:set-drawing-color black
  gis:draw shapefile 0.5

   ;; ask patches  gis:intersecting BE_WAL_Parcels_2015
;;  [ set is-farm? true]
  let n 1
  foreach gis:feature-list-of BE_WAL_Parcels_2015 [
    polygone ->
    let center-point gis:location-of gis:centroid-of polygone

    let x-coordinate item 0 center-point
    let y-coordinate item 1 center-point
;; I need to add here the possibility to move the centroid of one px and py
    
    ask patch x-coordinate y-coordinate [
      
      ifelse (ID-parcel = 0) [
      ;; set an ID to the patch
      set ID-temp n
      set ID-parcel gis:property-value polygone "ID_PRCL"
      set ID-farm gis:property-value polygone "ID_FARM"
      
       [ set pcolor red
        print x-coordinate]
        
      ]
      
      set n n + 1
    ]
```

I added an ifelse condition to make sure that one polygons centroid is not overlapping a precedent computed polygon (`set pcolor to red`). I know that 1871 polygons are overlapping each other, see the a small part of the world:
[image]

I'd like to add the following action: if the patches is already defined with an id-parcel, then move to the closest one that is empty.

1. I'm now sure where to write that since the `ifelse` is inside a `ask patch` procedure...
2. Moreover, I've been playsing with the world size and patch size to minimize the risk of overlapping but the shapefile seems to adapt to the world size/patch size. Is there a way to increase the number of patches inside one polygon ? So make the patches smaller without decreasing the size of polygons
   I attach here printscreen of a small part of the world as support
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

*****My second question is still OPEN (world and patch size)***** but I managed to find a way out (at least, it looks like OK) **for my first question** by sprouting a turtle on any patches that welcome a parcel from the shapefile, and afterwards checking whether there is already a turtle on the patche before assigning the next parcels. Here below is the few lines of codes. Any comment is obviously welcome ! :)

```
to setup-parcels
  ca
  reset-timer
  resize-world 1500 * 0 ( 1500 * 1 )  ( 1500 * -1 ) 1500 * 0

  gis:load-coordinate-system "BE_WAL_Parcels2006_Netlogo_selection_2.prj"

  set BE_WAL_Parcels_2006 gis:load-dataset "BE_WAL_Parcels2006_Netlogo_selection_2.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of BE_WAL_Parcels_2006)
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  gis:set-drawing-color black
  gis:draw BE_WAL_Parcels_2006 0.5

  let n 1
  foreach gis:feature-list-of BE_WAL_Parcels_2006 [
    polygone ->
    let center-point gis:location-of gis:centroid-of polygone

    let x-coordinate item 0 center-point
    let y-coordinate item 1 center-point
  
    let occupied turtles with [xcor = x-coordinate AND ycor = y-coordinate]
    ifelse any? occupied [
    set x-coordinate (item 0 center-point + 1)
    set y-coordinate (item 1 center-point + 1)
    ask patch x-coordinate y-coordinate [
      sprout 1

      set ID-parcel gis:property-value polygone "ID_PRCL"
      print ID-parcel
      set ID-farm gis:property-value polygone "ID_FARM"
      ]
    ]

    [   
      ask patch x-coordinate y-coordinate [
      sprout 1
      set ID-parcel gis:property-value polygone "ID_PRCL"
      set ID-farm gis:property-value polygone "ID_FARM"
      ]
    ]
      set n n + 1
    ]
 clear-turtles   
end
```